# Can't resolve AWS RDS sql express server, Error, cant connect to ip,port

Tags: amazon-web-services

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLbOh.jpg

I have followed the guide, disabled my firewall, verified my security group allows access to everything (initially set to public).  Still, 2 installs of mysql won't let ssms connect.  No idea why this doesn't work

ACL

```
100
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW

*
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
DENY
```

Security Group that my db is using

```
All traffic
All
All
sg-23ae465c (default)
```

postgres gives me

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "posttest.cnmcgcqc8rkx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (52.2.0.231) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

mysql can connect, might have to go with that

ecurity groups are not under RDS, they are under EC2's console.  ACL's options are under VPC's console.  This is not even mentioned in the guide.  Seen someone connect on youtube with my exact settings...

Comment: is the issue resolved ?

Comment: @AmitK yes but sadly due to treatment on this site the answer will not be posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of many things with the given information. The first thing I would check if you know your security groups are set up correctly is to open the port on the Network ACL Inbound Rules.

Comment: My inbound rule is set to All traffic All All sg-23ae465c (default)

Comment: my acl has this nonsense set 
100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
* ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 DENY